# What is causing there to be a second delay between each rendering of a new color?

Tags: c, linux, graphics, sdl-2

so I am trying to dig into SDL2. So far I have built the following simple program. All it does is render a rectangle to the screen and have it changes colors rapidly.

**game.h**

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
typedef struct Game {
bool finished;
SDL_Event curevent;
SDL_Window* mainwin;
SDL_Renderer* mainren;
}Game;

Game *initGame();
void destoryGame(Game*);
void drawRect(Game*);
void handleEvents(Game*);
```

**game.c**

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

#include"game.h"

Game *initGame() {
    Game *game = NULL;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s",SDL_GetError());
    } else {
        game = malloc(sizeof(Game));
        game->finished = false;
        game->mainwin = SDL_CreateWindow("Main Window",
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                         800, 640,
                                         SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        if(game->mainwin == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s",SDL_GetError());
        } else {
            game->mainren = SDL_CreateRenderer(game->mainwin, -1,
                                               SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if(game->mainren == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s",SDL_GetError());
            } else {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game->mainren,0,0,0,0xFF);
                SDL_RenderClear(game->mainren);
            }
        }
    }
    return game;
}

void destoryGame(Game *game) {
    free(game);
    SDL_Quit();
    printf("Exiting ...\n");
}

void handleEvents(Game *game) {

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&(game->curevent)) != 0) {
        if(game->curevent.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            game->finished = true;
        }
    }
}

void drawRect(Game *game) {
    int r, b, g, h, w;
    srand(time(NULL));
    r = rand() % 0xFF + 1;
    b = rand() % 0xFF + 1;
    g = rand() % 0xFF + 1;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(game->mainwin,&h,&w);
    SDL_Rect rect = {h/4,w/4,h/2,h/2};
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game->mainren,r,b,g,0xFF);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(game->mainren, &rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(game->mainren);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include"game.h"
int main() {
    Game* game = initGame();
    do {
        handleEvents(game);
        drawRect(game);
    } while((game->finished != true));
    destoryGame(game);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on a Linux system. Ubuntu 16.04. And am compiling with:

```
SRC_FILES = ./src/main.c ./src/game.c
CC_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Os -g -lSDL2 -std=gnu11
CC = gcc

all:
    ${CC} ${SRC_FILES} -o game ${CC_FLAGS}
```

This program compiles and runs no problem. The out put looks like this:

http://imgur.com/U5B6hB0

I am wondering why there is a second delay between each new color?

Intuition would tell me that there would be a new color each time the loop iterates. Which should be hundreds of times a second. Maybe looking something like this:

https://youtu.be/AjbrmfjJRk0?t=6m3s

What is causing this delay? Or am I miss understanding something about the code and it is doing exactly as it should be?

Comment: the function: `srand()` should only be called once for the whole execution of a program, not every time some random numbers are wanted.  Suggest moving the call to `srand()` to the first code line in function: `main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pseudo-random number generator generates a predictable sequence of numbers by using a calculation on the previous value.

For a simple example:

```
int lastValue;

int rand(void) {
    lastValue = (lastValue * 13) / 7;
    return lastValue;
}
```

Of course a real implementation of `rand()` is more complex.

When there is no previous number you'd have to use a default, and if the default is always the same (e.g. always zero when you start a program) it'd always generate the exact same sequence for all programs.

To fix this you're able to set an "initial previous number", or a seed number. This is what `srand()` is for.

Now...

You're using `srand()` every time you draw a rectangle, and getting the seed value from the current time. If the current time doesn't change, the seed is the same, so the sequences of numbers is the same as last time.

The current time changes once per second.

Comment: Wow. Thanks to both of you guys for figuring this out and explaining it to me. This was very eye opening.

Answer (score 3):

You are re-seeding the random number generator with your call to `srand()` in drawRect. You are providing the return value of `time()` as your new seed, and this only changes once every second since it reports the time in seconds since the start of the epoch. You then call `rand()` to get random RGB values for the color of your rectangle.

Because you are re-seeding the RNG with the return value of `time()`, you only see a new random color approximately every second even though your main function is calling `drawRect()` quite often. You might think that `rand()` should still give you a different 'random' value, but this is not how most RNGs work. Many of them give predictable sequences of numbers for a given seed value, hence the term 'pseudo-random number generator'. This actually has benefits in terms of testability.

If you eliminate the call to `srand()`, or move it outside of `drawRect()` (and preferably outside of your main game loop), you should see the colors change much more frequently.

Comment: Wow. Thanks to both of you guys for figuring this out and explaining it to me. This was very eye opening.

Comment: Here is some further explanation from the C language FAQ http://c-faq.com/lib/srand.html